# Cannot find sourceVersion Error while reading from EventHub and writing to delta lake

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to read from a EventHub, and writing to a 2 delta lake table, pseudo code below

```
// read from event hub
inputDF = spark.readstream().format(“eventhubs”).option(“consumerGroup”,”myapp”)

//write to 1 delta lake
inputDF.writestream().format(“delta”).option(“checkpointLocation”,”loc1”).start(“table_1”)

//write to 2 delta lake
inputDF.writestream().format(“delta”).option(“checkpointLocation”,”loc2”).start(“table_2”)
```

when i start my job it fails with message "Cannot find sourceVersion" below message

```
ERROR: Query termination received for [id=5735eea9-a2c0-42bf-b368-0918985bff3e, runId=88c17d32-d5d9-46b6-bb9c-19f5ab8598c5], with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find 'sourceVersion' in {"My_EventHub_Event_Name":{"2":25,"5":33,"4":35,"7":33,"1":26,"3":28,"6":30,"0":32}}
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.sources.DeltaSourceOffset$.validateSourceVersion(DeltaSourceOffset.scala:91)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.sources.DeltaSourceOffset$.apply(DeltaSourceOffset.scala:74)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.sources.DeltaSource.getBatch(DeltaSource.scala:269)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are the checkpoints new locations or they where used before,? i had seen this happen if i use the same checkpoint location and change the input source